# How to connect to multiple MySQL database on two different servers

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to connect to my localhost database (allinone), retrieve a couple of records and send them to an other database (imbigass_allinone) on my Server.

When I do a "mysql_num_rows" on both databases, this works fine. (query2) Which means, that I could connect to both databases on my Server and the localhost.

But what I can't figure out, how to fetch any records from my localhost database (allinone) and then send them on to the database (imbigass_allinone) on my Server.

Normally I use PDO but I have an old XAMPP Version which doesn't handle PDO.

```
$db_local = mysql_connect("localhost", "imbi", "aaaaaaaaaa", true);
$db_hostpoint = mysql_connect("imbigass.mysql.db.hostpoint.ch", "imbigass_imbi", "xxxxxxxxx", true);
mysql_select_db("allinone", $db_local);
mysql_select_db("imbigass_allinone", $db_hostpoint);

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `filenames`", $db_local); 
$result = mysql_db_query($query1) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $filename_id = $row['filename_id'];
    $filename_type = $row['filename_type'];
echo "$filename_id | $filename_type <br>";
}

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `filenames`", $db_hostpoint); 
$row_table2 = mysql_num_rows($query2);
echo "Filenames: ".$row_table2." - ".$row_table2."<br>";
```

PS Just figured out how to read from my localhost database:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filenames limit 10", $db_local);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $filename_id = $row['filename_id'];
    $filename_type = $row['filename_type'];
    $filename_filename = $row['filename_filename'];
    echo "$filename_id | $filename_type | $filename_filename <br>";
}
```

But the insert to the host database doesn't work now:

```
$insert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO filenames (filename_type, filename_filename) VALUES ('$filename_type', '$filename_filename')", $db_hostpoint);
$result2 = mysql_query($insert2) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

It just sends the first record to the host database. Then I get the error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: It all works now. A bis slow but it works.

Comment: Please don't use comments for adding details or clarifying your question: use the "edit" button instead. Best regards

Comment: I've edited your post to put most of your findings into it; it would be nice of you clarify the rest, add an answer to your question and accept it (once it's possible): this way, your question can be helpful for others once they find it

Answer (score 0):

This is the Code that connects to multiple MySQL databases on two different Servers.

```
$db_local = mysql_connect("localhost", "imbi", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", true);
$db_hostpoint = mysql_connect("imbigass.mysql.db.hostpoint.ch", "imbigass_imbi", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", true);
mysql_select_db("allinone", $db_local);
mysql_select_db("imbigass_allinone", $db_hostpoint);

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filenames", $db_local); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $filename_type = $row['filename_type'];
    $filename_filename = $row['filename_filename'];

    echo "$filename_id | $filename_type | $filename_filename <br>";

    $insert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO filenames (filename_type, filename_filename) VALUES ('$filename_type', '$filename_filename')", $db_hostpoint);
}
```

Comment: mysql_connect has no validity now. So don't suggest this type of old code. It has security questions also

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I still use XAMPP with PHP 5.3.8 and this Version, as far as I understand, doesn't handle PDO and this way I managed to have multiple Connections to different Servers.